# How do I add a sphere as a new shape?

Tags: objects

I've tried to add a second sphere to my scene and it's not coming up as a new object. If I attempt to do anything to the new sphere it messes with the one that is suppose to be an individual object.

Comment: @moonboots - Isn't it just "Tab"?

Comment: @Christopher Bennett oops yes you're right

Comment: They're both "right", I guess - Ctrl+Tab brings up a pie menu that lets you do the same thing (among others).  - It's just that when I read your comment, It made me second guess what I've been doing all these years, to the point that I had to actually open blender and check again ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between *object mode* and *edit mode*.
If you add a primitive (like a sphere) in *object mode* it will create a new object, otherwise it will just add the new vertices to the pre-existing mesh you're editing.